# Access Box Name When Using Ansible for Vagrant Provisioning

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I'm trying to do provisioning for a Vagrant multimachine setup with Ansible. I've got it installing the software I was after, but I want to be able to load in machine specific configuration it can use for things like the host name and domain. I had thought I would be able to access the name of the box as a variable, but nothing I've tried seems to be able to access that. Does anyone know what I can add to an ansible playbook for Vagrant provisioning to access the host name variable?

Comment: Do you mean `{{ inventory_hostname }}`? Also check this section in the docs: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#information-discovered-from-systems-facts

Comment: Fantastic, that's the one I'm after, and thanks for the reference to the docs. I'd been using ansible_hostname, which seems to load the name of the box being used rather than the name of the machine

Comment: If you stick this as an answer I'll mark it as being solved

Comment: Thanks David, added an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hostname can be accessed with `{{ inventory_hostname }}`. This is the name as defined in the inventory of Ansible. Also there is `{{ ansible_hostname }}` which is the discovered hostname.

From [Magic Variables, and How To Access Information About Other Hosts](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts)

> Additionally, inventory_hostname is the name of the hostname as configured in Ansible’s inventory host file. This can be useful for when you don’t want to rely on the discovered hostname ansible_hostname or for other mysterious reasons. If you have a long FQDN, inventory_hostname_short also contains the part up to the first period, without the rest of the domain.

Also see [Information Discovered from Systems Facts](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#information-discovered-from-systems-facts).